# User registers after contributing to the site? In Django

Tags: django, session, django-sessions, django-users

Let's say I have a site where users can contribute content.

If the user is anonymous, and contributes, and comes back after their session is expired, then their contributions are credited to Anonymous.

If the user is anonymous, and contributes content, and then creates an account, how can I credite all the user's contributions during this session to the user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is often called "Lazy Registration" or "Lazy Signup". There is a Django app to support this type of feature http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-lazysignup/ though I've never used it personally.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer storing the posted content IDs in the session.

There's no extra data stored on your content. There's no ever growing list of fake users.

And most importantly, your design pattern stays simple. Literally a few lines of code and unchanged behavior for the rest of django. Simplicity is important!

```
# registration_view

if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()
    posted_content =  request.session.get('posted_content')
    if posted_content:
        Content.objects.filter(id__in=posted_content).update(user=user)
```

As for crediting users that have expired sessions, I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can store the session id as part of the contributed content(property) and during the registration process to run a check against this session id.